# How to request a signature remotely from your own account in docusign with nodejs

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I will try my best to explain my problem in as much depth as possible.

My usecase:
I want to request my user to sign a document that I will be sending to his/her email through my nodejs application using my own docusign account.

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-email-remote/

The above link is all I want except for one change. The authentication step. I don't want to prompt the user to authenticate their account to send the document. Instead, I would like to authenticate my own account, get token and send the document to my user's email. Just like mailgun, where you receive your authentication keys once, you store it into your env and you can keep sending emails through your account.

https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/How-do-I-get-signatures-on-a-document-New-DocuSign-Experience?language=en_US&rsc_301

The above link is a resource that can help to send the documents via docusign interface. I want to achieve the same using my nodejs application.

The question can be pretty confusing, so let me know if you need anymore clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're asking about [authentication](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/).
You want to use your account, not have your users log-in.

You can achieve this using [JWT](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/).

Please take a look at the [MyHR Sample App](https://myhr.sampleapps.docusign.com/) as an example. It has two login buttons. One is using JWT and is hardcoded with an account, the other is letting you use [Auth Code Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/) and your account.

You want the JWT account button.

With JWT you impersonate a fixed user and that user is always going to be the one used for API calls.

Comment: Hello Inbar,
So you are saying that I should manually generate an access token through the method explained on this link
"https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/"
and then store this access token to make the api calls by always binding this token. Right?

And MYHR Sample App is exactly what I want thanks for that

Comment: No, the access token expires. You have to generate a new one the same way every time you want to make API calls

Comment: Need more clarification Inbar. This is not a practical way to manually generate the access token each time it gets expired. This is going to be on a production app where a lot of users will be using it. Even I automate it, the admin cannot give consent each time a user comes and wants to use the application. Also the sampleHr site does not require any consent, it worked directly.

Comment: You said before there's only one user. Are there many users?

Comment: The MyHR sample app uses a single user for JWT. So that can be done. If you need many users, they each user has to give consent. That's why it matters.

Comment: Let me explain my problem again.

Users will come to my application and will fill out a form. When they submit that form I will use that information to create a document and will send it to their email address to get their signature on that document. The DocuSign account I will use to send the documents is going to be the account of the admin of this application not the user's account.

Comment: Now, I want to authenticate the admin's account and will like to get a permanent access token that I can save in my env and will use to send documents to my users. According to your solution, each time a user comes to my application fills up the form and submits it, I will have to ask the admin for his consent and then I will be able to send the documents to that user's email.

Comment: In myhrsample website, I just clicked the button and the user was authenticated automatically (no consent was asked) and that is what I want. Just think that on that button click I would like to authenticate my admin's account without asking his consent every time.

I hope this will add some more clarification to my question.

Comment: you can do the same as MyHR. You just have to use JWT with a fixed account and generate the token each time. This is done without users having to do anything. JWT gives you exactly what you want and you can do your exact scenario. Please look at our JWT code examples and try them out to see how this works.

Comment: Thanks solved with your guidance. Really appreciate your time.